# Get unique list of top level element names in XML column of SQL table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which returns a column of XML values, for simplicity let's say this query is:

```
select top 1000 XmlColumn from MyTable
```

This returns a column with 1000 values, these contain XML.

I would like to extract the element name from only the top level element. So then I can transform these into a table of distinct element names.

How can I do this in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select  XmlColumn.value('local-name(/*[1])','varchar(100)')
 from MyTable
```